# Does ActionMode automatically refresh ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-actionmode

I can't figure out how my `ListView` is refreshing itself after deleting an item in `onActionItemClicked`.

```
@Override
public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_item_delete_notification:
            mNotifications.remove(0);
            actionMode.finish();
            return true;
            …
```

Obviously I realize the item I am deleting in this code sample is not dynamically chosen, I just put this for example purposes. After deleting an item it will automatically refresh the `ListView` without me calling `notifyDatasetChanged()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ActionMode.finish` makes a call to `ActionMode.onDestroyActionMode` in `AbsListView` which then calls `View.requestLayout`. `ActionMode.onActionItemClicked` will only invoke the action of a `MenuItem`.

I also notice you're calling `mNotifications.remove(0)`. I don't know if that indicates an `ArrayAdapter`, but `ArrayAdapter.remove` makes a call to `BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged`.

Comment: `mNotifications` is a `List`. So do you mean `View.requestLayout` is the underlying call that is responsible for refreshing the `ListView`?

Comment: Also, I [can't find a call](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/search?q=%22void+ondestroyactionmode%22&type=Code) from onDestroyActionMode to requestLayout

Comment: Hard to look this up on my phone, but yes.  https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/AbsListView.java#L6356.   https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/AdapterView.java#L794

Comment: Oh interesting, those weren't picked up through my github search query. Thanks for the help. Much appreciated.